# Recursively rewrite function

Tags: function-construction, functional

Let's imagine I already have a function like

```
myfac[0] :=1
myfac[n_ /; n>=0] := n myfac[n-1]
```

this home grown factorial.

Now I want to equip it with tracing (and I don't want to use the built in tracing). How can a write a higher order function that records the argument, like

```
tracing[f_] := Function[n, {n, f[n]}]
```

but such that each occurrence of f (in particular in the function definition of the recursive function) is replaced by tracing[f] ?

For example I want that tracing[myfac][3] evaluates to

```
(* {3, {2, {1, {0,6}}}} *)
```

Comment: `TracePrint[myfac[3]]` provides a trace (as a start). Oh, I see now you don't want built-in tracing. My bad.

Comment: I know there is a built in Trace function for this case. This is only an example, my actual problem is similar but more involved. I would like to understand how to wrap a function in another function whenever it is called.